# Youtube videos not working for Tizen device

Tags: tizen

I want to play youtube videos on my tizen device samsung application but it loose the control for app and open it in the web browser I use the iframe of youtube but it's also not working for me the iframe opens but video is not display for me

So i tried to implement this but it's opening the video in browser and if it opens in iframe the video is not visible but audio is working i am not able to clearify that it is playing on background.

Comment: Hello, would you add some codes for reviewers?